# Disable anchor with onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem to disable my anchor when its being pressed.

HTML:

```
<a href='#' data-bind='click: clickActivateSpatialSearch' id='draw_polygon'>
<i class='polygon_mark'></i>
</a>
<a href='#' data-bind='click: clickActivateSpatialSearchBox' id='draw_box'>
<i class='square_mark'></i>
</a>
```

jQuery

```
    $('.square_mark').click(function () {
        if(!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
            $(this).addClass('active');
            $('.polygon_mark').off('click', disabler);
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
            $('.polygon_mark').on('click', disabler);
        }
    });
    $('.polygon_mark').click(function () {
        if(!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
            $(this).addClass('active');
            $('.square_mark').off('click', disabler);
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
            $('.square_mark').on('click', disabler);
        }
    });
});
```

Function:

```
disabler: function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
},
```

The functionality to change classes are working fine, but what I wanted to add into this, os when anchor #1 is being pressed, this disables the other anchor, and when I press it once again, I'd like it to reenable the anchor, and also the other way around but for anchor #2.

I tried doing something like this, but I cannot get it to work, not fully understanding it either.

Comment: What exactly does not work? What buttons do you press and what happens not as expected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this and add a disable class to your css.

```
$('.square_mark').click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
        $('.polygon_mark').toggleClass("disabled");
});

$('.polygon_mark').click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
        $('.square_mark').toggleClass("disabled");
});
```

this should do the tric.

```
.disabled {
   pointer-events: none;
   cursor: default;
}
```

**Edit:** example on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uKCYN/

And if you need to check for the active class to do something else you can code it like this:

```
$('.square_mark').click(function () {
    if(!$(this).hasClass('active'))
        $(this).addClass('active');
    else
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    $('.polygon_mark').toggleClass("disabled");
});

$('.polygon_mark').click(function () {
    if(!$(this).hasClass('active'))
        $(this).addClass('active');
    else
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    $('.square_mark').toggleClass("disabled");
});
```

and add your additional stuff into the if clauses.

Comment: I did like you said, but I dont want to remove one of the classes, heres fiddle for you to see
http://jsfiddle.net/ZHqx5/

Comment: you don't need to code toggle twice ... as it does the action in both directions ... if an element has that class it removes it, if it doesn't it adds it. Look into the fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/uKCYN/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ZHqx5/1/ I tried it, but nothing happend, it still intiated the click command even though I had already pressed the other one.

Comment: The thing is that, the .active class, needs to be toggled, for visual effect, so it needs to be there.
But I want when its being pressed, to disable everything on the other one, untill I have pressed same anchor once again to reenable.

Comment: yes ... i messed up with the fiddle link ... look into the one i provided in the  answer update. The toggle adds an active class to the element you clicked and a disabled class to the other element, and removes both again when you press again.

Comment: I need the if to stay aswell, since I want it to see if its active or not, and then toggle a specific button image and all this is working fine, but what I do need is to add the toggleClass disabled, but I guess I could just add it inside my if right?

Comment: yes ... here i show you how. And you don't use the toggle inside the if ... as it already checks for the class. http://jsfiddle.net/uKCYN/1/

Comment: Works great! Though I did notice one thing, it disables, but the functionality still works even though its disabled?

Comment: Sorry @Martin my misstake, needed to do some changes, now its working!
THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

Just modify the handler function like this and try again:

```
// handler function
function disabler(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('item anchor clicked');
}
```